# Convert T-SQL to OVER / PARTITION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I really don't understand the T-SQL (2012) OVER and PARTITION BY clauses. But rather than getting yet another explanation that I won't understand, I was wondering if this can be converted to something using OVER? Or even some other syntax that's more concise.

```
update m
    set unique_count =
    (
        select count(*) from
        (
            select distinct client_id, member_id, claim_begin_dt
            from #claims c
            where c.client_id = m.client_id and c.member_id = m.member_id
        ) r1
    )
from #members m
```

In other words, I want to update each record in #members with the count of the member's claims that occur on unique dates.

By the way, if there's a syntax error in the above, ignore it (if possible). The code this was copied from works, but I changed some names and stuff to make it more clear.

Thanks.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, windowing functions won't work with DISTINCT.  There are a few ways to write your query.  Here's one that may be more readable:

```
UPDATE m
  SET unique_count = c.unique_count
FROM #members m
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT claim_begin_dt) unique_count
  FROM m
  WHERE client_id = m.client_id and member_id = m.member_id
) c
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer, not because of the SQL example, but because of letting me know that windowing functions won't work with distinct. Thanks for that.

Comment: @DanThomas . . . It seems irrelevant that window functions don't work with distinct given that window functions are not appropriate for this problem.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. However, I didn't know that window functions are not appropriate for this situation. You didn't say that in your response, for example. However, knowing that they won't work with DISTINCT was the only comment I got on the subject, and that was enough to tell me not to bother with them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `join` rather than window functions:

```
update m
    set unique_count = c.cnt
    from #members m join
         (select client_id, member_id, count(distinct claim_begin_dt) as cnt
          from #claims c
          group by client_id, member_id
         ) c
         on c.client_id = m.client_id and c.member_id = m.member_id;
```

This may not be faster (or it might be).  It is a bit more concise.

Comment: Thanks. I actually prefer the syntax I used. I think it's more clear that the join. LOL - this is just a matter of preference. "Ask any 5 programmers..."